# Can the result of a SUM be directly pointed/assigned to a an indirect cell n Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to know if its possible to assign a value to indirect cell address something like
below formula, because I am not sure of the exact position of the J cell currently and only K1 has it where K1 is using a lookup formula and gives a number. Hence the below formula. I know it does not work, But i need a formula, which makes it work.

J(INDIRECT("K1")) = SUM(M1:M10)

Comment: No, you can't. VBA coding can do that.

Comment: And perhaps you should try =indirect("J"&K1) as a structure... But it won't work for what you want anyway, see @Harun24HR

Comment: ok thank you for your response @Harun24HR , Solar Mike